# Sometime getting java.io.IOException: Pipe closed from jsch while file transferring

Tags: sftp, jsch

Sometimes we are getting java.io.IOException: Pipe closed error while transferring file from FTP.
Do you guys have any suggestion or solution for this issue?

Here is the stack trace:

```
2.15.1.redhat-621216 | JSCH -> Disconnecting from secure.test.com port 22
2019-02-05 14:56:58,755 | WARN  | renewals/request | SftpConsumer                     | 130 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.15.1.redhat-621216 | Error processing file RemoteFile[myTestFile.xml] due to Cannot change directory to: ... Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot change directory to: ..]
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot change directory to: ..
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.doChangeDirectory(SftpOperations.java:542)[134:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.15.1.redhat-621216]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.changeCurrentDirectory(SftpOperations.java:530)[134:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.15.1.redhat-621216]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFileToFileInLocalWorkDirectory(SftpOperations.java:741)[134:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.15.1.redhat-621216]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFile(SftpOperations.java:591)[134:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.15.1.redhat-621216]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:396)[130:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621216]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:137)[134:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.15.1.redhat-621216]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211)[130:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621216]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)[130:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621216]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)[130:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621216]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)[130:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621216]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)[:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)[:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)[:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)[:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: 4: 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:359)[64:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch:0.1.51.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.doChangeDirectory(SftpOperations.java:540)[134:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.15.1.redhat-621216]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:307)[:1.8.0_171]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream.updateReadSide(Channel.java:362)[64:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch:0.1.51.1]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:337)[64:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch:0.1.51.1]
    ... 17 more
2019-02-05 14:57:58,757 | INFO  | renewals/request | SftpOperations                   | 134 - org.apache.camel.camel-ftp -
```

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be able to tell you why the server closed the connection based on what little information you've given here. You should troubleshoot on the server what might have happened around this time.